# How to restrict Login access with LDAP client to an OU in Windows AD

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have inherited a web app which supports login via ldap (SSO). For testing this feature I have created an openLDAP server on Linux and a Windows 2019 AD server.

In the App's ldap client settings, I can set the default OU. Authentication works fine against the openLDAP server and restricts access to users in the default OU. When authenticating against the Windows AD, access is not restricted to the default OU but is granted to anyone in any OU.

I'm assuming the request is good since it works correctly with the openLDAP server.

I am new to both LDAP and Windows AD and any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm inclined to think the web app should have the ability to authorize users based on some criteria. Perhaps a group membership. That's separate from the authentication.

Comment: @GregAskew I did try using a 'group' in AD but had the same results - anyone in the AD could login. I am currently trying to figure out the exact request syntax being sent and the response. But am still not sure why AD would respond differently than openLDAP

Comment: Sounds more like a craplication.

Comment: "why AD would respond differently" – same reason why Postgres responds differently than MySQL, even though you use SQL for both. In particular, there are certain filter syntaxes that OpenLDAP supports but AD does not, and vice versa (such as ":dn:=" filters that only work in OpenLDAP, or the ":1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=" filter that only works in AD), and there are certain pseudo attributes that both systems have differently named (e.g. distinguishedName vs entryDN). So you really need to find out whether the application is using them, e.g. it *could* be using OpenLDAP-only `(ou:dn:=Foo)`.